# Is java.util.UUID.randomUUID copyable?

Tags: scala

I have a question on whether it is possible to perform a scala case class copy (or clone) on a field defined by `java.util.UUID.randomUUID`.

Suppose I have my class set up as

```
case class X(){
val id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString()
}
```

I create an instance of X and also attempt to clone the class. What I noticed is that the id fields are different. Is this expected and if so, is there a way to ensure that all copy / clone methods return the same value of id?

```
val z = X()
z.id != z.copy().id
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not that it is a `UUID` the problem is that you are misusing / misunderstanding how **case classes** work.

The `copy` method of a case class is just a convenient call to the constructor of the class. So for example

```
final case class Foo(a: Int, b: String)
```

Is expanded by the compiler to something like this:

```
final class Foo(val a: Int, val b: String) {
  def copy(a: Int = this.a, b: String = this.b): Foo =
    new Foo(a, b)

  // A bunch of other methods.
}

object Foo extends (Int, String) => Foo {
  override def apply(a: Int, b: String): Foo =
    new Foo(a, b)

  // A bunch of other methods.
}
```

So as you can see the `copy` is not black magic, it is just a simple method with default arguments.

So nothing in the body of the case class is included in the copy, so in your code the `id` field will be created for each instance as a call to `java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString()`

The best would be to do this:

```
final case class X(id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString)
```

This way you can omit it in creation but it will be preserved by `copy`. You may move it at the end of the parameter list so you do not need to use named arguments always when creating it.

Comment: That was helpful. Thanks!